# How can I change the order of execution of two loops?

Tags: python, node-editor, animation-nodes

How can I change the order of the execution of multiple loops inside an AN node graph?

I have an `A` and `B` loop, `A` runs first then `B`. However, I want `B` to run first and then `A` to run. Rewiring the entire tree would be tedious at this point.

[image]

**Q:** How can I change the order of execution of two loops?

Comment: Can u show your node tree?

Comment: I added an image to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a weird way of doing it,
Since your first and second loop are independent(i guess). we can put them in separate node trees. Then control execution of these two node trees using another.

[image]

Note that Auto Execution must be turned off for first two trees.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the interesting idea, I guess it is logical I will give it a try.

Comment: I think this is the most logical way to do it :) Helps keeping the logic separate if both loops are independent

Comment: How do I add 2 inputs to the expression node? And what is the type of the input for the expression node which holds the first and second variables?

Comment: I tried it with generic one and I get all kinds of errors when I try node execution of this final node group https://paste.debian.net/hidden/53de252a/

Comment: You don't have to specify type just connect to the input socket, AN automatically create generic input socket for you.

Comment: Can u share file?